# How to use dynamic color grading as similar as tailwindCSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is the code for tailwind:
`<div class="bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 ..."></div>`

I want to use CSS with a class name `secondary-navbar` without using TailwindCSS.

What should be inside CSS files to implement same result as above?

Comment: You can open the [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) - paste in your css class names to one of the divs, and use the chrome inspector to inspect the styles of the element, and copy those into your local css

Answer (score 0):

You want a background gradient right?

```css
.secondary-navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondary-navbar">
</div>
```

And search the internet for the right color codes for indigo-500